# How to setup with mixte authentification

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation

I'm trying to install a SharePoint server 2013.

In requirements, I have to use mixte authentication. Which choice do I make in the setup wizard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a post and mixte authentification are configured when creating a web application.
Here is what i follow
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/